# NoClassDefFoundError apache commons UrlValidator in GAE with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, apache-commons, noclassdeffounderror

i am using the apache commons UrlValidator in one of my java files.
the file compiles fine but whenever i run it, i get a NoClassDefFoundError for the UrlValidator class

i am using Google App Engine 1.7.5 with Eclipse Juno for JavaEE. i have included the the commons jar file in the build path as well as in the run config of my project under source but i still get the same error.

heres the code of my java file:

```
package com.serv.servshare;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PreparedQuery;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query;
import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.UrlValidator;

public class Share extends HttpServlet implements Servlet{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

DatastoreService ds;
String link,email,msgBody,title,name;
String[] schemes={"https","http","ftp"};
UrlValidator urlValidator;
boolean valid;
Query q;
PrintWriter out;
PreparedQuery pq;
Properties props;
Session session;
Message msg;

public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res)throws ServletException,IOException{

    title=req.getParameter("title").toString();
    link=req.getParameter("link").toString();
    //Instantiate UrlValidator
    urlValidator = new UrlValidator(schemes);
    out=res.getWriter();

    //Validate URL
    if (urlValidator.isValid(link)) {
           valid=true;
        } 
    else {
           valid=false;
        }

    if(valid){
        try{

            ds=DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
            q=new Query("email");
            pq=ds.prepare(q);

            //Query database to get all email ids
            for(Entity result : pq.asIterable()){

                email=result.getProperty("email").toString();
                name=result.getProperty("name").toString();

                //Instantiating the email prerequisites
                props=new Properties();
                session=Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
                msgBody=link;
                msg = new MimeMessage(session);
                msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("webmaster@servshare.appspotmail.com", "WebMaster@ServShare"));
                msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(email, name));
                msg.setSubject(title);
                msg.setText(msgBody);

                //Sending out the uploaded link to all subscribers
                Transport.send(msg);

                out.println("<html><head><title>ServShare</title><meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"3; URL=index.jsp\"></head><body>Email sent! You will be redirected to the home page shortly.</body></html>");
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            out.println("<html><body>An error was encountered while processing your request. Please go back and try again");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    else{
        out.println("<html><head><title>ServShare</title><meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"3; URL=index.jsp\"></head><body>The entered URL is not valid. You will be redirected to the home page shortly.</body></html>");
    }
}

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)throws IOException,ServletException{
    service(req,res);
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)throws IOException,ServletException{
    service(req,res);
}

}
```

and heres the error:

HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /Share. Reason:

```
org/apache/commons/validator/routines/UrlValidator
```

Caused by:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/validator/routines/UrlValidator
    at com.serv.servshare.Share.service(Share.java:41)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:61)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.validator.routines.UrlValidator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:213)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 34 more
Caused by:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.validator.routines.UrlValidator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:213)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at com.serv.servshare.Share.service(Share.java:41)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:61)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Powered by Jetty://

i have no idea as to whats causing this.
Thanks for any help.

i added these three files: commons-validator-1.4.0.jar, commons-validator-1.4.0-javadoc.jar, and commons-validator-1.4.0-sources.jar. 
i added them to the project thorugh project properties -> java build path -> libraries -> add external jars. 
i added them to the run/debug settings under my project: run/debug ->  -> source -> add

Comment: I think you should explicitly state the jar file names and how you added them to the runtime classpath.

Comment: i didnt get you. how do you mean explicitly?

Comment: You just said 'commons jar files'. Can you tell us the real file names of the jar files, and how you added them to 'run config'?

Comment: i added these three files: commons-validator-1.4.0.jar, commons-validator-1.4.0-javadoc.jar, and commons-validator-1.4.0-sources.jar. 

i added them to the project thorugh project properties -> java build path -> libraries -> add external jars. 

i added them to the run/debug settings under my project: run/debug -> <project> -> source -> add.

Comment: Can you update the original question with those information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if you add those files to war/WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: no change, except that the bottom half of the error message following caused by no longer shows

Comment: What happens if you remove those jars under run/debug -> source?

Comment: weird thing this....i restarted eclipse after i restarted my computer, all of a sudden its working fine.
One more thing, now the code executes fine and the mail is also sent, i can see it in the console but i dont receive the mail. i sent a mail to myself yesterday, still havent gotten it. Is there anyway to debug this?